# org.hibernate.MappingException:No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using postgres v8.3 which has a columntype as XML. DDL looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
"ID" INTEGER NOT NULL , 
"NAME" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
"Details" XML , ......
```

In the mapping hbm.xml file I map it like this:

```
<key-property name="Details" type="java.lang.String" >
<column name="Details" />
</key-property>
```

and I guess this is the reason of error : 
No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
when I run a select query using :

```
List<?> contactList= session.createSQLQuery("select * from contact where id=" + val.getId() + " and name= '" + val.getName + "'").list();
```

but what is the other way I can map "XML" type to a java datatype ?

Comment: nIKUNJ's answer is correct, it fixed the issue for me. I ran into this problem while upgrading from spring 2.x to spring 3.  
  
Not sure why the mismatched mapping of string to an xml column worked before, but the upgrade definitely started causing these:
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify your custom column type using `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType` class provided by hibernate.

[Here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hibernate_XML_Type) is very good example.

Thanks.

Comment: In that example, how does Hibernate know to *create* an XML column? The `sqlTypes()` method returns `{ Types.VARCHAR }`

Answer (score 1):

`Use addScalar();`

For example

```
session.createSQLQuery("select public.flcpool_backup()")
                                     .addScalar("id", Hibernate.BIG_INTEGER)
                                     .addScalar("caf_tbl_id", Hibernate.BIG_INTEGER)
                                     .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining connection dialect "[`hibernate.dialect`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects)" in hibernate.cfg.xml for postgres.